# RxJava: How to combine List of objects to List of another objects group by

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have the List of SourceObjects and I need to convert it to the List of ResultObjects using group by name

```
class SourceObject {
  private String name;
  private String grade;
}

class ResultObject {
  private String name;
  private List<String> grades;
}
```

Basically, I need to group by name and add all grades of students to ResultObject, so if there are x number of SourceObject, then the number of ResultObject should be <= x.
For `SourceObject` having the same name, they will transform to one `ResultObject`

Input:`Single<SourceObject>`

Ouput:`Single<ResultObject>`

Answer (score 0):

Turn the inner list into a sequence, collect the result via a HashMap then map the values back to a list:

```java
Single<List<SourceObject>> source = ...

Single<List<ResultObject>> result = source
   .flattenAsObservable(v -> v)
   .collect(
       () -> new HashMap<String, ResultObject>(),
       (map, item) -> map.computeIfAbsent(item.name, 
             k -> new ResultObject(k)).grades.add(item.grade))
   )
   .<List<ResultObject>>map(map -> new ArrayList<ResultObject>(map.values()))
   ;
```